# implementing a convolutional autoencoder using VGG pretrained model as the encoder in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

Iḿ implementing a convolutional autoencoder using VGG pretrained model as the encoder in tensorflow and calculation the construction loss but the tf session does not complete running because of the Incompatible shapes: [32,150528] vs. [32,301056] the loss calculation. the problem that the dimension ?

```
class VGG_Autoencoder(object):
    def __init__(self, model_path="vgg_saved_models/", learning_rate=1e-3):
        self.model_path = model_path
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 300, 300, 3], name='image')
        self.resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(self.inputs, [224, 224])

    def encoder(self, input):
        with tfs.arg_scope(nets.vgg.vgg_arg_scope()):
            _, layers = nets.vgg.vgg_16(inputs=input, is_training=False)
        fc7 = layers["vgg_16/fc7"]
        fc8 = tf.layers.dense(fc7, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="fc8")
        fc8_flat = tf.layers.flatten(fc8)
        fc8_flat_dense = tf.layers.dense(fc8_flat, units=512, name="fc8_flatten_dense")
        return fc8_flat_dense

    def decoder(self, bottleneck):
        fc_bottleneck = tf.layers.dense(bottleneck, units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="fc_bottleneck")
        bn_resh = tf.reshape(bottleneck, [-1, 4, 4, 16])
        conv_9 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(bn_resh, filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same',
                                       activation=tf.nn.relu)
        conv_10 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv_9, filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same',
                                       activation=tf.nn.relu)
        conv_11 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv_10, filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same',
                                       activation=tf.nn.relu)
        conv_12 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv_11, filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same',
                                       activation=tf.nn.relu)
        conv_13 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv_12, filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=7, padding='same',
                                       activation=tf.nn.relu)
        conv_14 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv_13, filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same',
                                       activation=tf.nn.relu)
        conv_15 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv_14, filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same',
                                       activation=tf.nn.relu)
        conv_16 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv_15, filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same',
                                       activation=tf.nn.relu)
        conv_17 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv_16, filters=16, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same',
                                       activation=tf.nn.relu)
        conv_18 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv_17, filters=16, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same',
                                       activation=tf.nn.relu)
        conv_19 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv_18, filters=3, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same',
                                       activation=None)
        #output = tf.image.resize_images(conv_18, [224, 224])

        return conv_19

    def loss(self, input_image, reconstructed_image):
        tf.Print(input_image, [tf.shape(input_image)])
        tf.Print(reconstructed_image, [tf.shape(reconstructed_image)])

        input_image_ = tf.reshape(input_image, [32, -1])
        reconstructed_image_ = tf.reshape(reconstructed_image, [32, -1])
        reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(input_image_ - reconstructed_image_), axis=1)

        loss = tf.reduce_mean(reconstruction_loss)
        return loss

    def optmizer(self, loss, learning_rate, global_step):
        restore_fn = tf.contrib.framework.get_variables_to_restore
        fc7_variables = restore_fn(exclude=["vgg_16/fc8"])
        sub_variables = fc7_variables[29:]
        init_var = tf.variables_initializer(sub_variables)
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=sub_variables, global_step=global_step, name="fcn_train_op")

    def summary(self, input_image, reconstructed_image, loss):
        input_resized_image = tf.summary.image('resized_image', input_image, 20)
        output_resized_image = tf.summary.image('constructed_image', reconstructed_image, 20)
        loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
        merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
        return merged

    def data_iterator(self, batch_size):
        data_files = glob.glob('/home/WIN-UNI-DUE/sjmonagi/Desktop/dataset/Train/**/VAE_FloorPlan*', recursive=True)
        while True:
            data = np.load(random.sample(data_files, 1)[0])
            np.random.shuffle(data)
            np.random.shuffle(data)
            N = data.shape[0]
            start = np.random.randint(0, N - batch_size)
            yield data[start:start + batch_size]

def train_nn():

        sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)

        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logdir_vgg')

        VGG = VGG_Autoencoder()
        model_name = VGG.model_path + 'model'
        images = VGG.data_iterator(32)
        bottle_neck = VGG.encoder(VGG.resized_image)
        output_images = VGG.decoder(bottle_neck)
        loss = VGG.loss(VGG.resized_image, output_images)
        VGG.optmizer(loss, VGG.learning_rate, global_step=global_step)
        merged = VGG.summary(VGG.resized_image, output_images, loss)
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1)
        step = global_step.eval()
        try:
            saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(VGG.model_path))
            print("Model restored from: {}".format(VGG.model_path))
        except:
            print("Could not restore saved model")

        while True:
            images = next(images)
            _, loss_value, summary = sess.run([loss, merged],
                                              feed_dict={VGG.inputs: images})

            if np.isnan(loss_value):
                raise ValueError('Loss value is NaN')
            if step % 10 == 0 and step > 0:
                print('step {}: training loss {:.6f}'.format(step, loss_value))
                save_path = saver.save(sess, model_name, global_step=global_step)
            if loss_value <= 35:
                print('step {}: training loss {:.6f}'.format(step, loss_value))
                save_path = saver.save(sess, model_name, global_step=global_step)
                break
            step += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    train_nn()
'''**
```

Comment: You aren't very clear as to where exactly the code is failing, but I assume you noticed that the rhs of the problematic dimension is exactly double the lhs? This hints that you're missing (or have an extra) strided layer with stride 2. Just follow through with the tensor-shapes, even with a debugger, and decide where you want to add (or remove) a 2-stride.

Comment: The error is at the loss calculations, as you said the dimension are double, but i do not know where the dimensions are doubled from, i used the debugger to check the output of the encoder and it match the resized input which is [None, 224,224,3], The dimensions are changed during the session run and cannot debug where this is actually happens ?

Comment: Maybe it's only a specific image. I'd run through the data and insure all the images are of the wanted size.